# How to create translation to "timesince" value ? (template tag)

Tags: django, django-templates

I review docs but I am lost... some problem with it:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% blocktrans %}
{{ wpis.entry.lastChangeDate|timesince }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Raise:

```
`KeyError: u'wpis.entry.lastChangeDate | timesince'`
```

Of course, without blocktrans all works fine.

So, what is simples way to translate few words? (I am interesting polish lang, minutes -> minut, hours -> godzin, etc)
I will be thankful for clear example.

EDIT:
in my .po file i have now:

```
#: templates/part.html:37 
#, python-format 
msgid "" 
"\n" 
"%(lastChangeDate)s\n" 
msgstr ""
```

and i don't see anything about var in docs... now i would do:

```
msgid "hours" 
msgstr "godzin"
```

etc and bind it to my var (above example don't work...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% load i18n %}
{% blocktrans with wpis.entry.lastChangeDate|timesince as lastChangeDate %}
{{ lastChangeDate }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#in-template-code for more info.

Comment: Thx for answer, but in that case where i should put polish words?

Comment: But i still have only english words, in setting.py lang is "pl"

Comment: It sounds like you don't have internationalization setup properly. Do you have the locale middlware installed, and have you created your language files? See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

Comment: in my .po file i have now: #: templates/part.html:37
#, python-format
msgid ""
"\n"
"%(lastChangeDate)s\n"
msgstr ""

and i don't see anything about var in docs... 
now i would do: 
msgid "hours"
msgstr "godzin"
etc and bind it to my var

Comment: This is outdated. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `{{ var|timesince }}` and make sure that in settings.py, `LANGUAGE_CODE` is set to your locale and that `USE_I18N` is `True`.

You don't need to use blocktrans or have custom translations in a .po file for this, it's already included.